# Query_post($args)

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

it is possible to use a array by the this query?

---

#### This Version doesnt work:

$args = array(
    'order'    => 'ASC',
        **'meta_key => array('city_1','city_2),

    'meta_value' => array('NY','LA')**
);

query_posts($args);
--------------

#### And this Version works:

$args = array(
    'order'    => 'ASC',
        **'meta_key => 'city_1',

    'meta_value' => 'LA'**
);

query_posts($args);
--------------

have somebody a idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [multiple custom field handling in WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'city_1',
            'value' => array('NY','LA'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'city_2',
            'value' => array('NY','LA'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
query_posts($args);
```